# Conditional Probability ambiguity

Tags: probability

**There are two children in a household. What is the probability that both are boys, given that it is known that at least one is a boy? What is the probability that both are boys if it is known that the elder child is a boy?**

What I did for the first question was to simply divide the possibility of them both being boys with the possibility that at least one was a boy (using the rule of conditional probability).

So I got the answer $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}=0.5$ as the probability.

I first wanted to check if this is indeed the right approach for the first question.

Also, I am struggling to understand how the second question is supposed to be different. Isn't the second question also saying that at least one is a boy? I don't see how the age would be relevant. One interpretation I had was to treat the given probability as having a first child as a boy over a girl (which would be the denominator). And then the numerator would be having both as boys:

$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2}{3}=0.67$

But I am not convinced this is the correct interpretation.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Try the very long and detailed [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) about the usual answer, and all the variants and arguments.  BTW make sure you read the part about the boy being born on a Tuesday -- it makes a difference...  I'm not joking!

Comment: Oh this is excellent! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you are told that the children in order are $BB, BG, $ or $GB$.  Presumably these are equally probable.  The chance both are boys is therefore $\frac 13$.

For the second, you are told they are $BB$ or $BG$.  The chance they are both boys is $\frac 12$

Comment: No, I am listing the children in birth order.  $BG$ and $GB$ are two different orders.  If you view $BG$ as representing both, it is twice as likely as $BB$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I see that now!